# How to assign return value of a function into a variable in c++?

Tags: c++, variables, return

i want to assign a returned value of a function into a Variable in C++, but the program is exit without any output.

```
int numberPosition = binarySearch(arr, num, searchNumber);
```

[program output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INsRt.png)

Full code---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int binarySearch(int arr[], int num, int searchNumber){
    int start=0, end=num;

    while(start<=end){
        int mid = (start+end) / 2;
        if(arr[mid] == searchNumber){
            return mid;
        }else if(arr[mid] <= searchNumber){
            start = mid+1;
        }else{
            end = mid-1;
        }
    }
    
    return -1;
}

int main(){
    
    int num, arr[num], searchNumber;
    cout<<"How many Elements u want to insert? \n";
    
    cin>>num;
    
    cout<<"\n Enter ut Numbers:- \n";
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    
    cout<<"\n Enter the Number u want to search:- ";
    cin>>searchNumber;
    
    int numberPosition = binarySearch(arr, num, searchNumber);
    
    if(numberPosition){
        cout<<searchNumber<<" is founded at position: "<<numberPosition;
    }else{
        cout<<searchNumber<<" is Not Founded";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen when you ran that program?

Comment: Did you put any output statements in the program?

Comment: Please edit this to include a minimal reproducible example. How do you expect people to help if we don't know how you've written `binarySearch`, `arr`, `num`, or `searchNumber`?

Comment: Assigning the returned value to a variable doesn't output that value. You probably want to do something like `#import <iostream>` and then after the line you included, do `std::cout << numberPosition << "\n";`.

Comment: ok sorry...
i'm including full code

Comment: @NathanPierson now i included full code

Comment: Does your code compile without [warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/)? Those would be the first things to address.

Comment: you need to declare the array with length num after you have taken the input of variable num. it's causing error because of that

Comment: ohh i make a simple mistake @amankapoor thnks it's works now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here This code works. You need to declare the length of array with variable num after you have taken the input value of num.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int binarySearch(int arr[], int num, int searchNumber){
int start=0, end=num;

while(start<=end){
    int mid = (start+end) / 2;
    if(arr[mid] == searchNumber){
        return mid;
    }else if(arr[mid] <= searchNumber){
        start = mid+1;
    }else{
        end = mid-1;
    }
}

return -1;
}

int main(){

int num, searchNumber;
cout<<"How many Elements u want to insert? \n";

cin>>num;
int arr[num];
cout<<"\n Enter ut Numbers:- \n";
for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
    cin>>arr[i];
}

cout<<"\n Enter the Number u want to search:- ";
cin>>searchNumber;

int numberPosition = binarySearch(arr, num, searchNumber);

if(numberPosition!=-1){
    cout<<searchNumber<<" is founded at position: "<<numberPosition;
}else{
    cout<<searchNumber<<" is Not Founded";
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The return code I am able to see in your program screenshot is  `3221225725`. This return code means that `your computer ran out of stack memory before the recursion limit was reached.`.

So, you still have infinite recursion somewhere in your code.

So I think in your function `binarySearch(arr,num,searchNumber)`, You are recursively calling your function somewhere. As you didn't post the code of your function I can't help you on that where you made the mistake.

So make sure your Implementation is correct.
The correct implementation of the binary search `c++` function is

```
int binarySearch(int arr[], int l, int r, int x) 
{ 
    if (r >= l) { 
        int mid = l + (r - l) / 2; 

        if (arr[mid] == x) 
            return mid; 

        if (arr[mid] > x) 
            return binarySearch(arr, l, mid - 1, x); 

        return binarySearch(arr, mid + 1, r, x); 
    } 

    return -1; 
}
```